Credit card provider told to take the full balance every month, but doesn't do it. Am I liable for overdraft fees?
One of the transactions on my credit card, on may 27th was approx £1k for car insurance.
I've told my provider (capital one, uk) to take the full balance every month.
I continually find that they don't actually do this; on June 2nd they took a direct debit of only around £540; together with the other transactions paid out, this means they left a total of £1200 on the account.
I'm hoping that I've misunderstood what "full balance" means to these folks; but I got an SMS warning me that I was close to my credit limit and was surprised to see that they, seemingly intentionally, took a smaller payment than what I consider to be the full balance earlier this month, and with other transactions, I'm now close to the limit.
Is this evidence of shenanigans on their part (they are a famous, reputable supplier) or have I misunderstood what they mean?
There was a point in the past when I made a payment for the full balance as I saw on screen, after which they took a direct debit and we found ourselves in the hilarious situation of the credit card owing me money.
Update:
The credit card company now owes me money because I paid the full balance (to avoid going overdrawn) then 3 days later they took a direct debit for the full balance.
Not relevant to the question but I thought it would be funny anyway.

Is this question about credit cards in the UK? Please don't answer in the comments; instead, edit your question to add united-kingdom as a tag.

Thanks
Added the tag

It may be that the accounting period for your card is not the same as the calendar month.  There are typically a few weeks between the statement date and the date that a direct debit is performed.

There are two dates which will appear on your statement: the statement date, and the direct debit (DD) date. The latter will be 2-3 weeks after the former, depending on the card.
Whatever your account balance is, as shown in the statement on the statement date: that is the amount that will be taken from your account on the DD date, and it will not increase.
Any transactions you make after the statement date will not be included in this DD; instead, they will appear on your next statement, and included in the DD in a month's time.
So is it possible that you made the £1000 payment after this month's statement date? (You'll know if this is the case, as it won't appear on the statement.) If so, you will see it on next month's statement instead, and it will be paid 2-3 weeks after that.

This is correct, and as long as you pay the full balance on that next payment, you won't be charged any interest. If you want to be able to spend more on the card between now and then, you can make a payment to the card before the next statement date, and that will reduce your current balance (and reduce the amount that is debited in the next DD).

And if you google "credit card billing cycle" and do an image search, you will find lots of diagrams that explain this graphically on a timeline.

Normally "full balance" means balance as of the billing date, just as it would if you were paying by mail, not the balance at the date they transfer money from your account.
As with the mailed payment, that's enough to keep you from being charged interest (except on things like cash advances where there is no grace period and interest starts immediately).
This does mean it's  possible to hit your credit cap between the billing and payment dates... again, just as if you had paid by mail. You have the tradeoff of asking them to take the money earlier to reduce that risk, or closer to the due date to keep the money in your own account (paying interest, hopefully) a bit longer).
